# Cyclic Metadata Dependency when using JSONDecoder on Generic Codables

Tags: generics, swift4, codable

Swift 4's Foundation library now has a built-in JSON parser.  It works well except for an issue I'm having when using it in a particular way.  If the object being decoded is referenced as a generic inside another struct (example below), the decoder generates a runtime error:

> GenericCache(0x106a31830): cyclic metadata dependency detected,
>   aborting

Here's an example JSON string coming back from a service:

```
{"data": { "type": "foo", "attributes": { "name": "Fooey McFooface", "age": 23 }}}
```

Here are the two corresponding Swift 4 data models:

```
struct GenericWrapper<S: Codable>: Codable {
    struct GenericWrapperData<T: Codable>: Codable {
        let type: String
        let attributes: T
    }
    let data: GenericWrapperData<S>
}

public struct Foo: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
}
```

Given the above examples, this code will trigger a runtime error:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(GenericWrapper<Foo>.self, from: jsonData)
```

Here's a project that demonstrates the above code:

https://github.com/UberNick/CodeableGenericBug

I'm wondering whether that nested struct that GenericWrapper uses is a problem.  Many of the guides on using Codable use those in their example.  And the nested structs do work when inner struct's variable definition "attributes: T" is replaced by a concrete type like "attributes: Foo".  It also works when the inner structure (GenericWrapperData) is defined externally.  Those working cases are also in the above-linked example project.

My question is why the runtime bug?  Is this a framework issue or is there something wrong with the code?